# How do I update eclipse from 4.2.1 to 4.2.2 on a nonInternet facing machine?

Tags: eclipse, updates, update-site

We have several test networks and the machines on these networks do not have internet access.  I am trying to install Worklight 6.2 studio ... but it requires Eclipse 4.2.2 minimum and this is an RDz install with 4.2.1.  A simple "update" on an internet facing maching would work fine.  I tried bringing a fresh 4.2.2 down, but not surprisingly it did not recognize it as a repository.  What is best way to update Eclipse w/no internet connection (I can move files up there from elsewhere).  Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Facing the same issue before, I found a tip from the [Eclipse help reference](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/update_standalone.html) that details steps to clone an update site as an offline mirror:

```
Mirroring feature(s) from a remote site:
java -jar plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_<version>.jar
    -application  org.eclipse.update.core.standaloneUpdate
    -command mirror
    -from remote_site_url 
    -to target_site_dir
    [-featureId feature_id]
    [-version version]
    [-mirrorURL mirror_site_url]
```

The only downside to this is that you will have to clone not only the main Eclipse mirror, but also any specific plugin sites, but once done you will have a full offline update site:

```
/eclipse
   -application org.eclipse.update.core.standaloneUpdate
   -command mirror
   -from http://www.some-plugin-site.com/update-site
   -to /path/to/local/directory
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for this quick response. I downloaded 4.2.2 on a machine that does have the internet, and tried:
java -jar plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar -application  org.eclipse.update.core.standaloneUpdate -command mirror -from http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.2 -to /home/mcasile/swRepos/eclipseUpdateSite

And I fail and the log sayjava.lang.RuntimeException: Application "org.eclipse.update.core.standaloneUpdate" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunners: ...  Maybe my syntax?

Comment: One more Q ... is there an ability to enhance a normal download into an update site (ie: generate update site metaData from the content)?  I may be in left field as the formats may all be different, but it seems that it would be quite nice in my predicament to download 4.2.2 and enhance it to be an update site as well.  Thanks again.

Comment: "One more Q" - This is not how stackoverflow works. Don't ask follow-up questions but new questions instead.